# To get the position of a letter from a (column)string in a table

Tags: postgresql-9.2

I have a database  employee as

#### EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME   SALARY      DEPARTMENT   JOINING_DATE

```
      1       John      Abraham     1000000      Banking     2013-01-01
      2       Michael   Clarke      800000       Insurance   2013-01-01 
      3       Roy       Thomas      700000       Banking     2013-02-01
```

My Query is to :**`Get position of 'o' in name 'John' from employee table!`** in postgresql!

I have tried with :: `SELECT position('o' IN 'John');` But I want to get John from the table! is there a way to doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT position('o' IN FIRST_NAME) FROM employee WHERE FIRST_NAME = 'John';
```

If you want the position in the full name, you could do this:

```
SELECT position('o' IN FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST NAME) FROM employee WHERE FIRST_NAME = 'John';
```

Comment: its working, but if at all i need to select a employee from the table whose name is john i.e..,(first_name=john) then how to achieve it

Comment: @RobinHood's See my updates to the queries. I added a WHERE condition